# Use local Internet connection

Tags: networking, vpn, ethernet

I have a network split into through two ethernet segments through a virtual VPN hub.

[image: network topology]

In the figure, blue is the part of the network that I control. My problem is due to the orange subnetwork, that I don't control, the local path from segment 1 to the internet is not taken (I undestand that it is because it contains one more hop), but instead the much slower path through the vpn ethernet hub is used. I'm a total newbie here, there prebably is a very simple way of taking care of this.

How can I ensure that each segment uses it's local router in preference to the other?

Comment: Both work for me. Thanks to your answer I realized that I just needed to cut the traffic of DHCP packets through the VPN hub. Then all computers in either segment would get their configuration from independent DHCPs... it feels a bit hackish for now but it will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the default route for hosts in segment 1 to the local route on segment 1, and that for hosts in segment 2 to the router on segment 2.

This will be somewhat more painful if you're using DHCP, but since the network is segmented, it should still be perfectly possible.